# repo data is not showing in hygieia dashboard

Tags: devops, cicd, hygieia

Can anyone help me for the hygieia setup
I am facing issue with code analysis
below is the screenshot of the dashboard

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGFYg.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure the SCM GitHub Collector, execute the following steps:

git clone the https://github.com/Hygieia/hygieia-scm-github-collector Then, execute the following steps:

To package the SCM GitHub collector source code into an executable JAR file,

run the maven build from the \hygieia-scm-github-collector directory of your source code installation:

mvn install

The output file hygieia-scm-github-collector.jar is generated in the hygieia-scm-github-collector\target folder.

Set the configurable parameters in the application.properties file to connect to the Dashboard MongoDB database instance, including properties required by the GitHub Collector.

Then

logging.file=./logs/github.log
github.cron=0 0/5 * * * *

github.host=github.com

github.commitThresholdDays=15
github.errorThreshold=1

github.personalAccessToken=

Then save and go to target folder
Run below command

hygieia-scm-github-collector\target>java -jar hygieia-scm-github-collector.jar